# How to make a nav tabs in bootstrap?

Tags: bootstrap-4, nav, bootstrap-tabs

I tried to make a secondary navigation menu using Nav Tabs from bootstrap for it shows me different content when I click on the different links  but it doesn't work. It only shows me the first about but when I click on the second link nothing happens. So how can i make it work ?

Here is my secondary menu code:

```
<div class="secondary-navbar">
                <div class="container">
                    <div class="row justify-content-center">
                        <div class="col-lg-8">
                            <nav class="secondary-menu">
                                <ul class="secondary-menu-list nav nav-tabs">
                                    <li class="nav-item secondary-menu-item active"><a href="#about" data-toggle="tab" id="about-tab" role="tab" aria-controls="about" aria-selected="true" class="secondary-menu-link menu-link active">About 1</a></li>
                                    <li class="nav-item secondary-menu-item"><a href="#about2" data-toggle="tab" id="about2-tab" role="tab" aria-controls="about2" aria-selected="false" class="secondary-menu-link menu-link">About 2</a></li>
                                </ul>
                            </nav>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

Here is what I want to display:

```
<div class="tab-content">
        <div class="tab-pane fade show active" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="about-tab" id="about">
            <main class="nk-pages">
                <section class="section pb-0 ov-h">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="nk-block">
                            <div class="section-head text-center">
                                <h2 class="title">About Us</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row gutter-vr-15px justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-mb-10">
                                    <div class="nk-block-text">
                                        <p>Centralized exchanges sacrifice security to achieve Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua ut enim ad minim </p>
                                        <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing plea sure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder.</p>
                                        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-mb-10">
                                    <div class="nk-block-text">
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
                                        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p> 
                                        <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing plea sure and praising pain was born and I will give you.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </main>
        </div>
        
        <div class="tab-pane fade" id="about2" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="about2-tab">
            <main class="nk-pages">
                <section class="section pb-0 ov-h">
                    <div class="container">
                        <div class="nk-block">
                            <div class="section-head text-center">
                                <h2 class="title">About Us 2</h2>
                            </div>
                            <div class="row gutter-vr-15px justify-content-center">
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-mb-10">
                                    <div class="nk-block-text">
                                        <p>Centralized exchanges sacrifice security to achieve Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua ut enim ad minim </p>
                                        <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing plea sure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder.</p>
                                        <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="col-lg-6 col-mb-10">
                                    <div class="nk-block-text">
                                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. </p>
                                        <p>Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p> 
                                        <p>But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing plea sure and praising pain was born and I will give you.</p>
                                    </div>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </section>
            </main>
        </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I copy pasted the thing, included the CSS/JS CDNs, and it works fine. Check here: [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/deathstalkersid/tdfLby8g/9/)

I am guessing you forgot to include the JS files needed for the tab functionality to work. You need these 2 for B4:

```
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/jquery@3.5.1/dist/jquery.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-fQybjgWLrvvRgtW6bFlB7jaZrFsaBXjsOMm/tB9LTS58ONXgqbR9W8oWht/amnpF" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```